# How to place a spinner in whichever HTML element was clicked

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to display a spinner icon whenever a user takes an action on my site. This is mostly going to happen when submitting a form via AJAX such as a comment reply, a pic upload etc. It may also happen when a user clicks on something that requires content to be loaded by AJAX.

Currently I have a single div to hold my spinner icon e.g. `<div id="ajax-spinner"></div>`. This is fixed to the top of the screen and it shown/hidden using JQuery's `beforeSend()` and `success` options in the ajax() method. A bit like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'some_url_that_processes_this_form',
            data:'data_to_send',

            beforeSend: function(){
            $("#ajax-spinner").show();
            },

            success: function(data)
            {
            $("#ajax-spinner").hide();
            }

           });
```

The problem is that its not very user friendly because where the spinner is shown is nowhere near the button they actually clicked. Its also not even in the same area as where they clicked.

What I'd like to do is show the spinner next to each and every element they click. So if they click a "Like" link, then I want the spinner next to that link. If they upload a picture, then I'd like the spinner to appear in the box that contains the image.

What would be the suggest design pattern to use to achieve this? Rather than have copies of the spinner available in each and every HTML tag, is there some way to dynamically position the spinner and dynamically resize it so that it can be reused on the page anywhere I want? Facebook has got this nailed if you want an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a CodePen of something that should get you started: http://codepen.io/trevanhetzel/pen/GsEuI

Basically, you need to capture the current mouse position when a form is submitted. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to do that with an `.on('submit')` event, BUT it is doable with an `.on('click')` event because you can pass a parameter through to a function to capture where you just clicked by using `pageX` and `pageY` methods.

This is not ideal, since you wanted it done inside a `beforeSend` action, but you could still do the showing and hiding inside the `beforeSend` and `success` calls, and just do the positioning on click.

Hope this helps!

**Super basic markup**

```
<div id="ajax-spinner"></div>

<form>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<form>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<form>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Super basic CSS**

```
form {
  margin: 20px;
}

#ajax-spinner {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

**JS**

```
jQuery('button').on('click', function (e) {
  var mousePosX = e.pageX,
      mousePosY = e.pageY;

  jQuery('#ajax-spinner')
    .show()
    .css('top', mousePosY, 'left', mousePosX);  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the div spinner position absolute and position it near the clicked control :

```
$("myselector").click(function () {
    $("#ajax-spinner").css("top", $(this).position().top);
    $("#ajax-spinner").css("left", $(this).position().left);

    //make the size you want it to be
    $("#ajax-spinner").css("width", "500px");
    $("#ajax-spinner").css("height", "500px");

});
```

You can ajust the top and left to accomplish what you want.

Comment: This is great. Any ideas on how to resize the spinner or should I have two versions e.g. sml and lrg

Comment: you can modify the height and width of the spinner or make large and small. I edited my answer.